# ROS Answers SE migration: Rosdep update

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to both Linux system and ROS, thus aks you for pacience.

Here is the deal: I tried to run rosdep update, than this happens:
(I had to hide the links in order to post this)

```
lpa@lpa-desktop:~$ rosdep update
...
ERROR: unable to process source [*link*]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
    HTTP Error 404: Not Found
ERROR: unable to process source [*link*]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
    HTTP Error 404: Not Found
updated cache in /home/lpa/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
ERROR: Not all sources were able to be updated.
[[[
ERROR: unable to process source [*link*]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
    HTTP Error 404: Not Found
ERROR: unable to process source [*link*]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
    HTTP Error 404: Not Found
]]]
```

Here is rosdep --version:

```
lpa@lpa-desktop:~$ rosdep --version
0.10.15
```

I have seen other issues involving this matter, but could not solve it, for I do not know enough of the matter yet, or the problem remained unsolved. It came to my knowledge that there is a version 0.10.18 of rosdep, which should be updated, ok. I try this:" sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade " as suggested in a message with this tittle: Re: [ros-users] Roll out of new rosdistro today  (seems I cannot publish links). Ok, but then, I get this:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-navigation : Depends: libyaml-cpp-dev but it is not installed
 ros-groovy-rviz : Depends: libyaml-cpp-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

if I repeat the command, adding -f , or running " sudo apt-get -f install " I get this:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libyaml-cpp-dev_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/yaml-cpp/aliasmanager.h', which is also in package yaml-cpp 0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

...

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libyaml-cpp-dev_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And then I get stuck, because I need to update rosdep, but cannot get the dependencies, right?
And when I try to get python-rosdep, I get this:

```
lpa@lpa-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-rosdep is already the newest version.
python-rosdep set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-camera-calibration-parsers : Depends: libyaml-cpp-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It tells also that the version I have is the newest, when its not, what do I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66697/rosdep-update/) by [Ohashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5336/ohashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-07-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-05**:
Please edit it but put a whitespace into your link so we can see the actual urls.  Once you get a few karma you can post valid links.

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2013-07-05**:
Looks like you're not reaching the repositories, and you have some broken packages. Which Linux distro are you using? Also it would help if you formatted the terminal output in your question as code (easier to read). You can do this by selecting the text and pressing the code format button.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-05**:
What platform are you using? Rosdep's current released version is 0.10.20

**Comment by [Ohashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5336/ohashi/) on 2013-07-07**:
according to rosdep --version , its 0.10.15 . I'll edit everything as soon as I can use the computer again, it's not in my home. The system is Ubuntu 12.10

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-09**:
Same kind of problem here. Anytime I try to update, I get 0.9.3 version for rosdep. Can't get the one you're talking about. The computer system is Ubuntu 12.04. dornhege solution didn't solve anything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Somehow the yaml-cpp package changed. The only way I could fix that is by simply uninstalling all ROS packages + everything yaml-cpp like. Reinstalling went smooth with the correct dependencies.

As everything is via apt-get that should be quick to do with two commands - unless you have a slow internet connection.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if it will solve everything, but what helped me to get the newest rosdep version (0.10.21) was to use this command line :

```
sudo pip install -U rosdep
```

that I found on this tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

hope that helps

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-09**:
Also this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/47177/rosdep-update-error/

**Comment by [Ohashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5336/ohashi/) on 2013-07-10**:
There is no pip in this system, I suppose I could try getting it for this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution proposed by dornhege worked for me, the code was the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove ^ros*
sudo apt-get remove --purge yaml-cpp
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full
```

As seen in this question: http: //answers.ros.org/question/51806/install-of-groovy-on-ubuntu-1210-problem/  It seems there were Fuerte packages here, causing a conflict.
Thanks for all the help.

---

Originally posted by [Ohashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5336/ohashi/) with karma: 58 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2